# setters and getters vs random name method to set or get

Tags: java

I wanted to know what's the difference between using a setter and getter to get & initialize an instance variable vs naming your own method to set and get an instance variable?

Does it change anything when calling `setCar()` to set a variable instead of `mesetCar()` or `initializeCar()`?

PS: This is not why use getters and setters instead of public fields its why name the methods setters and getters instead of a random method name

Comment: One conforms to the Java Bean standards first laid down in 1995; the other does not.   Any technology that depends on those standards will break if you use the random names. Worse, other people will have a harder time reading and understanding your code.  Deviate from the standards only when you have a very good reason.

Comment: *"does it change anything"* - Well, it's likely to change people's mood, as most Java developers are use to using things like `setXxx`/`getXxx`. They are, for the most part, also self documenting.  I'd also question any method called `initialize`, as the constructor should have done that

Answer (score 0):

No implications. Only a convention.

```
public void setName(String nm){
    Name = nm;
}

public void makeName(String nm){
    Name = nm;
}
```

These would perform the same function.